Prove that $Y=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are not independent
Given that $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $X_1，X_2,...,X_n$ is a set of samples and $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$, how to prove that $Y=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are not independent?
MY ATTEMPT:
I have tried:
$$
\begin{align}
Y=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2\\
=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X}+\bar{X}-\mu)^2\\
=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left[(X_i-\bar{X})^2+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2+2(X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-\mu)\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left[(X_i-\bar{X})^2+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\right]+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left[2(X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-\mu)\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left[(X_i-\bar{X})^2+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2+\frac{n}{\sigma^2}(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\\
\end{align}
$$
It's widely knowed that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent, and it's obvious that $\bar{X}$ is contained in $n(\bar{X}-\mu)^2$. It seems that $Y$ should not be independent with $\bar{X}$ as $Y$ is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ and $n(\bar{X}-\mu)^2$. However, I don't know how to prove that strictly.
How can we do that?

There is not really anything left to prove. You could say that for $Y$ to be independent of $\bar{X}$, the distribution of the marginal $\mathbb{P}(Y)$ needs to be equal to the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(Y | \bar{X})$, but this is obviously not the case since the expression for $Y$ depends explicitly on $\bar{X}$.

Hint: If $\bar{X},Y$ are not independent, the covariance $Cov(\bar{X},Y)$ will not be equal to $0$.
